# How to include custom non-system folder under This PC in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-8.1

I've recently upgraded from Windows 8 to 8.1 and noticed the restructured *This PC* folder, formerly *Computer*.

*What I want to achieve is to include custom folder under "This PC".*

[image: This PC]

What I've found after googling is that what is displayed under "This PC" is stored in registries under

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace`

However those folders (such as *Desktop*, *Documents*, etc) are referenced via *CLSID* and the folder I want to include in the list does not have *CLSID*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the tools **[FolderTweak for Win8.1](http://elvenbone.deviantart.com/art/FolderTweak-for-Win8-1-404879892)**

[image]

or **[This PC Tweaker](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.213)**

[image]

Both tools can add new items. Maybe they help you.

Comment: Updated links for Windows 10
**FolderTweak for Win10** https://www.deviantart.com/elvenbone/art/FolderTweak-for-Win10-623850518
**Winaero Tweaker** https://winaero.com/download-winaero-tweaker/

Answer (score 13):

You can also add folders by right clicking and selecting "Add Network Location." You can use a network path like `\\computername\users\me\whatever` to point to a folder on your local machine.

[image]

Then

[image]

Comment: Downvote care to comment?

Comment: Its not exactly the most detailed answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what more detail I could offer, it's a pretty simple solution. Can you give me an example of something that would help, or something that's not clear in the answer? I thought it was helpful to find a way to do this without installing third party software.

Comment: How a visual guide on how to do it.  A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Not as nice as the other solutions but does seem to work, I needed to add the drive letter-dollar sign, e.g. //computer-name/C$/users/nicks/Blah

Comment: Backslash works for me: `\\computer-name\c$\Users\john-doe\some-folder`. Thanks for the simple solution.

Comment: This will add the folder under `Network locations`. To add folders under `Folders` use the programs mentioned in the answer by magicandre1981

Answer (score 4):

I recently figured out how to do this manually and have added the answer to this question: https://superuser.com/a/914701/422795 - *"How can I create a new system folder to show up in “This PC” in Windows 8.1 without additional tools?"*.

It is not for the faint hearted though as it involves a lot of registry editing. However, if you're in a situation where you cannot download a 3rd party app (e.g. at work) and desperately want to add your own custom folder, it might be of help.

Comment: Definitely not for the faint hearted... :-)

Answer (score 1):

For windows 10, I used Winaero Tweaker. Under File Explorer-> Customize This PC Folder you can change the folders that are shown.

I'm not sure if this backports to windows 8 or not.