# How to sort custom system folders in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, filesystems, windows-10, windows-registry

Following [this](https://superuser.com/questions/840790/how-can-i-create-a-new-system-folder-to-show-up-in-this-pc-in-windows-8-1-with%20%20I) tutorial, I was able to create a custom system folder for Mega Sync:

[image]

However, now I'm sitting with another problem - how do I sort/move it? **I want it to sit between Creative Cloud & OneDrive folders.**

Afterwards, I plan on creating a second folder for Google Drive and putting it there as well.

Comment: Just as a side note, for other ppl searching for same question, try adding "Navigation pane" keyword to the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem myself.

A friend found [this](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/33844-libraries-move-above-pc-windows-8-1-a.html) tutorial, describing how to move libraries in windows explorer.

Using the same method, I applied a 32-bit DWORD named SortOrderIndex with a hexadecimal value of 42 to the two registry entries I made in [HKCR\CLSID] & [HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID]

As you can see in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpVwf.png), this fixed my problem :)

Comment: Did the same on windows 10 with custom cloud folders such as CloudStation and GoogleDrive: [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c8l58up3374azh4/custom_navigation_pane.png?dl=0)