# Add folder to Windows 10 Explorer's Folder section

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

How can I add some of my folder (as in image, `svn`) to the `Folder` section?
And, how can I remove the folder I never use (Pcitures / Videos / Music) from this section? 
[image]

Comment: [How to include custom non-system folder under This PC in Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/666049/how-to-include-custom-non-system-folder-under-this-pc-in-windows-8-1)

Comment: @Sandeep can you move this comment to answer so I could mark it answer? FolderTweak solve my problem!

Comment: This was answered by someone else. I just posted link to original answer. So, it would not be correct to post it as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This could have been found with a quick google.
Can I redirect you to https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6015-add-remove-folders-pc-windows-10-a.html
it adds or remove keys in

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}

But it seems you must know the GUID's of every folder, so that site is better.

*I HAVE NOT TESTED THIS. all standard warnings about regedit apply*

Comment: Downvote issued due to the condescending, “This could have been found with a quick google.”, statement